# Want to lip sync from Papagyo to a Rigify face rig using PoseLib? Here is the python script to do it

Tags: animation

This is a short python script to import moho files into an NLA strip. Bake the strip to an action and then refine if necessary.

For moho the required actions must be called AI, E, etc, FV,L,MBP,O,rest,U and WQ.
Create each pose and save as an asset.

It is quick and dirty but it is easy and it works. I am sure it can be improved.

Enjoy!

````
import bpy
# Creates a NLA strip of actions - intended for rapid lipsyncing using the PoseLib 3+ and Papagyo
# 1) Define the face poses for each phoneme
# 2) Load this script and run it. A panel will be added to the NLA 
# 3) In the NLA editor add a strip to the armature and set the field accordingly
# 4) Load the Moho file. The format is <fame> <Action Name>. This is the output from Papagyo, but any any list of actions could be supported if the pose has been defined.
# 5) The NLA strip will now be the list of assumed face actions
# 6) Bake the track to an action and edit as required
# 

# your rig ... or use bpy.context.active_object if you prefer
def loadMoho(context,rig,track, filepath):
    visTrack = rig.animation_data.nla_tracks[track]
    context.view_layer.objects.active = rig
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            words= line.split()
            if len(words) < 2:
                pass
            else:
                frame = int(words[0]) 
                if frame > 0:
                    vis = words[1]
                    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame
                    action = bpy.data.actions[vis]
                    if action is None:
                        continue
                    cycleStrip = visTrack.strips.new("Cycle",start=frame,action=action)
  


class MohoLoadOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_idname = 'cc.control_load'
    bl_label = 'Moho Load'
    filter_glob: bpy.props.StringProperty(default = '*.dat',options = {'HIDDEN'})
    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH")
    def execute(self, context):
        print("filepath=", self.filepath)
        rigName = context.scene.armature
        rig = bpy.data.objects[rigName] 
        track = context.scene.trackName
        loadMoho(context,rig,track,self.filepath)
        # load the moho file
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event): # See comments at end  [1]        
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)  
        #Open browser, take reference to 'self' read the path to selected 
        #file, put path in predetermined data structure self.filepath
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}  
        # Tells Blender to hang on for the slow user input

class MohoLoadPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Moho Load'
    bl_idname = 'cc.mohoload'
    bl_space_type = 'NLA_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop_search(context.scene, "armature", context.scene,"objects", text="Rig")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene,"viseme")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene,"trackName")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('cc.control_load', text='Load')



def add_properties():
    bpy.types.Scene.armature =  bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="armature",
        description="Rig to add face animation to",
        default="Armature",
    )
    bpy.types.Scene.viseme =  bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="viseme",
        description="Face animation file",
        default="viseme.dat",
    )
    bpy.types.Scene.trackName =  bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="trackName",
        description="Track Name",
        default="NlaTrack",
    )
    
        

def remove_properties():
    del bpy.types.Scene.armature
    del bpy.types.Scene.viseme
    del bpy.types.Scene.trackName



CLASSES = [
    MohoLoadOperator,
    MohoLoadPanel,
]

def register():
    for klass in CLASSES:
        bpy.utils.register_class(klass)
    add_properties()

def unregister():
    for klass in CLASSES:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(klass)
    remove_properties()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your post. To keep the Q&A structure of this site intact, you should describe the purpose of the script or what you want to do in the form of a question (edit 1st post). Then you can answer your own question with the script (2nd post).

Comment: By the way, what is "moho"? -- nevermind, found it: Moho Pro 13.5 | The all-in-one animation tool for professionals and digital artists | Software for PC and Mac OS for 328 bucks.